# trouble to stay connected to the node server when it becomes more than 10 sockets in server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

try to do chat with socket.io 
this is my server

```
var io = require('socket.io');
connect = require('connect');
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var sequelize = new Sequelize('XXXXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXXX');
var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(80,'myip');
var server_listen = io.listen(app);     
server_listen.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){         
            socket.on('entrance1',function(data){
                //insert socket id 
                if(!isNaN(parseFloat(data.user_id)) && isFinite(data.user_id)){
                    var friends_user='select substring(socket_id, 1, length(socket_id)) s from msg_users_sockets where user_id in (select user_id from base_friendship where (user_id='+data.user_id+' or friend_id= '+data.user_id+') and is_active=1) or user_id in (select friend_id from base_friendship where (user_id='+data.user_id+' or friend_id= '+data.user_id+') and is_active=1)';
                    sequelize.query('select * from msg_users_sockets where user_id='+data.user_id, null, {raw: true}).success(function(result){
                        if(result.length>0){
                            sequelize.query("INSERT INTO  `msg_users_sockets` (`user_id` ,`socket_id`,`cookie_id`)VALUES ('"+data.user_id+"',  '"+socket.id+"','"+result[0]['cookie_id']+"'); ").success(function(myTableRows) {});
                        }       
                        else{
                            var tim=new Date().getTime();
                            sequelize.query("INSERT INTO  `msg_users_sockets` (`user_id` ,`socket_id`,`cookie_id`)VALUES ('"+data.user_id+"',  '"+socket.id+"','"+tim+"'); ").success(function(myTableRows) {});
                        }   
                        sequelize.query(friends_user).success(function(result1){
                            socket.emit('online',{message:'you are online',user_id:data.user_id});
                            for(var i=0;i<result1.length;i++){
                                server_listen.sockets.socket(result1[i]['s']).emit('entrance',{message:'Anew chatter is online'+socket.id,user_id:data.user_id});
                            }                                           
                        }); 
                    });     
                }   
            });
            socket.on('remove_tab_user', function  (data) {
                if(!isNaN(parseFloat(data.user_id)) && isFinite(data.user_id)){
                    sequelize.query('select substring(socket_id, 1, length(socket_id)) s from msg_users_sockets where socket_id!="'+socket.id+'" and user_id='+data.user_id, null, {raw: true}).success(function(result){
                            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                            if(result[i]['s']!=socket.id)
                            server_listen.sockets.socket(result[i]['s']).emit('remove_tab_socket',data);
                        }           
                    });     
                }
            });
            socket.on('add_tab_user', function  (data) {
                if(!isNaN(parseFloat(data.user_id)) && isFinite(data.user_id)){
                    sequelize.query('select substring(socket_id, 1, length(socket_id)) s from msg_users_sockets where socket_id!="'+socket.id+'" and user_id='+data.user_id, null, {raw: true}).success(function(result){

                            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                                if(result[i]['s']!=socket.id)
                                server_listen.sockets.socket(result[i]['s']).emit('add_tab_socket',data);
                            }
                    });     
                }
            });         
            socket.on('chat', function  (data) {
            //  socket.broadcast.emit('updateusers',data);
                if(!isNaN(parseFloat(data[0].sender_id)) && isFinite(data[0].sender_id)){
                    var friends_user='select substring(socket_id, 1, length(socket_id)) s,socket_id i from msg_users_sockets where user_id in (select user_id from base_friendship where (user_id='+data[0].sender_id+' or friend_id= '+data[0].sender_id+') and is_active=1) or user_id in (select friend_id from base_friendship where (user_id='+data[0].sender_id+' or friend_id= '+data[0].sender_id+') and is_active=1)';
                    sequelize.query(friends_user, null, {raw: true}).success(function(result1){
                            for(var i=0;i<result1.length;i++){
                                if(result1[i]['s']!=socket.id)
                                server_listen.sockets.socket(result1[i]['s']).emit('updateusers',data);
                            }                                           
                        });                         
                }
            });
            socket.on('disconnect', function  () {              
                sequelize.query('select * from msg_users_sockets where  socket_id='+socket.id, null, {raw: true}).success(function(result){
                        if(result.length>0){
                            sequelize.query('select * from msg_users_sockets where  user_id='+result[0]['user_id'], null, {raw: true}).success(function(result2){
                                if(result2.length>0){
                                    var friends_user='select substring(socket_id, 1, length(socket_id)) s from msg_users_sockets where user_id in (select user_id from base_friendship where (user_id='+result[0]['user_id']+' or friend_id= '+result[0]['user_id']+') and is_active=1) or user_id in (select friend_id from base_friendship where (user_id='+result[0]['user_id']+' or friend_id= '+result[0]['user_id']+') and is_active=1)';
                                    sequelize.query(friends_user).success(function(result1){
                                            for(var i=0;i<result1.length;i++){
                                                server_listen.sockets.socket(result1[i]['s']).emit('entrance2',{message:'Anew chatter is online'+socket.id,user_id:result[0]['user_id']});
                                            }   
                                        }); 
                                    }                                   
                            }); 
                        }
                sequelize.query("delete from msg_users_sockets where socket_id="+socket.id).success(function(myTableRows) {

                    });                 
                server_listen.sockets.emit('entrance',{message:'Anew chatter is disconnect'+socket.id});                
                });
            });

    });
```

this is my client code:

```
var socket=io.connect('http://myib:80',{
'max re connection attempts':5,
'sync disconnect on unload':true
 });
```

this is client event
    'error'
    'reconnect_failed'
    'connect_failed'
and some event for chat...etc
when socket try to connect give me this warning:
    "websocket connection invalid"
ones or twice then socket connect 
 Sometimes socket disconnects 
when try socket to reconnect give me the same warning
When the number sockets 5 6 7 may begin in some cases cut off contact with some of these sockets and trying to connect again, but gives the same warning and keep trying and can't connect until re-load the page again

I'm using latest versions of node
I try 
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling", "jsonp-polling"]);
Please give me all the possibilities that cause this problem and its solution.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not enabling all of the transports which might be causing problem. Use this:

```
io.set('transports', [
'websocket',
'flashsocket',
'htmlfile',
'xhr-polling'
'jsonp-polling',
  ]);
});
```

Also, I'm doubtful about your reference to server in

```
var socket=io.connect('http://myib:80')
```

What is this myib??? Have you defined it already? You're supposed to put localhost or IP address in place of myib

Comment: Ofcourse I put myip ip instead and I try put the socket.io configuration without flashsocket